# How to get the HTML of a page that loads dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to scrape a website for content. I was able to get the HTML of the main page using a nodejs but I have found that the page is generated dynamically. Resources are requested from other sources and they aren't there yet when the HTML is grabbed on my end.

I've verified this with PhantomJS which allowed me to screengrab the page and generate a screenshot of what was being grabbed. The page definitely loads, but it's completely barren.

What I'm asking is, can this be done? Is CORS the issue here, or do I need to delay the loading somehow? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Delay the scraping until the page has given you all of the content you're looking for, either with a timeout, or by chaining the scrape into the completion event for the page loading.

Comment: Timeout was a no go. I get the same empty page waiting after 10 seconds.

Comment: What version is PhantomJS? What does `page.onError` callback say? Do you *have* to use node.js for this scrape or could a raw PhantomJS script do? Can you disclose the scraped URL?

Comment: @Vaviloff Thank you for the response. I was actually able to solve this issue using Nightmare which is a framework based on phantomjs. The documentation is on github if you're curious, but using Nightmare I was able to load a browser using JS which rendered the page as expected. Tomorrow, I'll play with extracting the HTML I need.

Comment: Everything Nightmare does, can be done in node.js+phantomjs or just in PhantomJS. Pity you didn't share your code, there was probably some sort of issue.

Comment: I could share it if you would still like to see it. At work now but if it's something that you would still like to see I don't mind posting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use streams it might be able to grab all of the data until there really is nothing left. Use the request library:

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('somefile.txt');
request('http://google.com').pipe(writeStream);
```

And if you want more control:

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('somefile.txt');
const r = request('http://google.com');
r.pipe(writeStream)
r.on('data', data => {
  console.log('Grabbing data!');
});

r.on('end', () => {
  console.log('data grabbing has ended')
});
```

Comment: Interesting... So the idea here is that it would generate the HTML in real-time similar to how a page is loaded when requested by the browser? ----- for sanity, can you confirm that I'm not experiencing any issues with their JS scripts? I should be able to load those even when requesting outside a real browser right?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can be done using phantom but I do find casperJS simple. It is built on top of PhantomJS but much simpler. It will let you access [iframes](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#switchtoframe) inside DOM and you can also use [waitfor](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector) function which allows you to wait for specific selector or other resources before executing/scraping which is very useful when dealing with the dynamic pages.

Answer (score -1):

Nightmare JS was the solution here... Using Nightmare I was able to open a browser and do all sorts of crazy things.

For those curious, the documentation is available on GitHub and on their website.

For those experiencing similar issues I really suggest checking it out.

[Nightmare JS website](http://www.nightmarejs.org/)
[Nightmare GitHub](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#api)